# URL variables on a Google 'My Maps'

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, url

So I have this:

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zkXLRR9SQKDQ.kfLF9HxBaALo&z=15" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I managed to find the zoom code on here, however I couldn't find a way to remove the grey bar that appears at the top of the map with my google account stuff.
A screenshot can be found [here](http://prntscr.com/53vx67).
Is there a way to remove this using a URL parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to remove the bar. Instead you could use the Google Maps Javascript API. It's fairly easy to use and gives you much more control. Here's an example that loads your location with the right zoom level: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/nndMjGDGOKKC3c0sPqyu?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4893169, -2.1182648);
      var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
      var image = 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Check-icon.png';
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Documentation for the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

If you need a specific style for your map, you can use the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Depending on where you put your map on your page, it might conflict with scrolling. If that is the case, then set the scrollwheel option to false. That allows you to scroll over the map without it highjacking the scroll event for it's zoom functionality. I've updated the plnkr to use scrollwheel: false.